# jQuery if/else statements using 2 checkboxes

Tags: jquery, if-statement, checkbox, charts, conditional-statements

I am building a chart that needs to change values depending on two checkboxes. I have 2 datasets, so I created 4 values for each. This is what I have so far:

HMTL / Checkboxes:

```
<input id="toggle-1" type="checkbox"/>

<input id="toggle-2" type="checkbox"/>
```

jQuery condition:

```
$("input#toggle-1[type='checkbox']").click(function (event) {
 var data = chart2.config.data;
 if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
  data.datasets[0].data = x;
  data.datasets[1].data = x;
 } else {
  data.datasets[0].data = x;
  data.datasets[1].data = x; 
}
chart2.update();
});
```

This would be the set up for only one checkbox `toggle-1` assuming I would replace the "x"s with each variable accordingly.

So how do I implement the condition for second checkbox?

I am using 2 datasets with 4 variations/combinations each:

Dataset 1:

```
Toggle-1(on) + Toggle-2(on) = x
Toggle-1(off) + Toggle-2(on) = x
Toggle-1(on) + Toggle-2(off) = x
Toggle-1(off) + Toggle-2(off) = x
```

Dataset 2:

```
Toggle-1(on) + Toggle-2(on) = x
Toggle-1(off) + Toggle-2(on) = x
Toggle-1(on) + Toggle-2(off) = x
Toggle-1(off) + Toggle-2(off) = x
```

Does that makes sense?

Comment: You want to avoid repeating (duplicated similar) code?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I am sorry but I don't think I understand your question. I want to make this work with 2 checkboxes.

Comment: Add more code, with this we can't do a thing. In your if/else you do same thing and when you use # for id you dont need element tagname and type

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://jsfiddle.net/kymvdz14/

Comment: @mark.hch That pretty much what I have right now. I need two check boxes, assuming that each checkbox has 2 values (checked / unchecked). So each dataset has 4 combinations.

Comment: @Marcio Another, with 4 data sets and the radios reverted to checkboxes: http://jsfiddle.net/2qd3up7f/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but wouldn't something like this helps?

```
$("#toggle-1, #toggle-2").click(function (event) {
    var chk1 = $("#toggle-1");
    var chk2 = $("#toggle-2");
    var data1, data2;

    if (chk1.is(':checked')) {
        if (chk2.is(':checked')) {
            data1 = x;
            data2 = x;
        } else {
            data1 = xx;
            data2 = xx;
        }
    } else {
        if (chk2.is(':checked')) {
            data1 = xxx;
            data2 = xxx;
        } else {
            data1 = xxxx;
            data2 = xxxx;
        }
    }

    var data = chart2.config.data;
    data.datasets[0].data = data1;
    data.datasets[1].data = data2;
    chart2.update();
});
```

Since you're using the id selector `#`, it should be unique enough that the `input` and `[type='checkbox']` is unnecessary.